# Why do these parts of speech change according to the following?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I'm using nltk to process a sentence, and I can't figure out why "hundred" here changes part of speech to a verb in these two sentences, and why "record" is a different part of speech as "record-setting"...

> nltk.pos_tag(lexnlp.nlp.en.tokens.get_token_list("I finished it in a respectable four hundred and five seconds"))
> [('I', 'PRP'), ('finished', 'VBD'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('respectable', 'JJ'), ('four', 'CD'), ('hundred', 'VBD'), ('and', 'CC'), ('five', 'CD'), ('seconds', 'NNS')]
>
> nltk.pos_tag(lexnlp.nlp.en.tokens.get_token_list("I finished it in a record four hundred and five seconds"))
> [('I', 'PRP'), ('finished', 'VBD'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('record', 'NN'), ('four', 'CD'), ('hundred', 'CD'), ('and', 'CC'), ('five', 'CD'), ('seconds', 'NNS')]
>
> nltk.pos_tag(lexnlp.nlp.en.tokens.get_token_list("I finished it in a record-setting four hundred and five seconds"))
> [('I', 'PRP'), ('finished', 'VBD'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('record-setting', 'JJ'), ('four', 'CD'), ('hundred', 'CD'), ('and', 'CC'), ('five', 'CD'), ('seconds', 'NNS')]

The definitions of these codes are

> - JJ: adjective or numeral, ordinal
>   third ill-mannered pre-war regrettable oiled calamitous first separable
> - CD: numeral, cardinal
>   mid-1890 nine-thirty forty-two one-tenth ten million 0.5
> - VBD: verb, past tense
>   dipped pleaded swiped regummed soaked tidied convened halted registered
> - NN: noun, common, singular or mass
>   common-carrier cabbage knuckle-duster Casino afghan shed thermostat

I get how its different somehow, since the the "finish" is "respectable" or "record-setting" but the "record" is "405 seconds", but **why would "hundred" be a verb in the "respectable" case here, and "numeric" when its record/record-setting ?**

(I think this could be a grammar concept I don't understand, not a bug in the nltk package, hence my post here. If this is not the case, I'll move it to vanilla stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I am not so sure you are in the right place for this type of question.

Comment: please read until the end of my post. To clarify, if this ends up being the case, I'll move it. I don't know enough about the grammatical rules here to rule out that this is an issue with my personal understanding of the rules, and not the code.

Comment: There is no English verb 'hundre' or 'hunder' for which 'hundred' could be its "past tense." I suggest submitting a bug report.

Comment: This looks more like "Please debug my code" than "How does English work?" If a question can't be phrased without requiring us to understand ***computer language*** syntax, I think it has no place on ELU.

Comment: (I assume the issue is just some crappy bit of code misparsing the last two letters of ***hundred*** as unambiguously identifying a past tense verb form. But who cares?)

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to "debug my code" at all. I'm asking a simple question about the part of speech. The code is simply for context, for why I would think that "hundred" would be a verb at all, if indeed it isn't. I guess it's not a verb based on the other (helpful) comments. That's all I wanted.

Comment: Also you don't have to "understand computer language", or even how the code works at all. You can see that a word is paired with a two letter code, and I've defined that two letter code.

Comment: I've reformatted the question to use block quotes, which is preferred here. But even with that, I have no idea what's actually being asked. If it's really a *why* question, that would seem to be entirely a matter of opinion. (*Why* questions are notoriously impossible to answer.)

Comment: Here, 'four hundred and five' is a numeral, a lexeme it's senseless to analyse further; 'record' gets the POS people at each others' throats arrogating that it's converted from an attributive noun to a true adjective (or not); and 'record-setting' is an adjective (compound & participial). Apologies for the super-commas, if they bother anybody.

Comment: The more appropriate ELU question might be: "Can the sentence "*I finished it in a respectable four hundred and five seconds*" be parsed such that the word '*hundred*' is a verb?"  Then your evidence of research might include the nltk parse.

Comment: @Cascabel I blame people who write long and ill-constructed sentences.

Comment: Edited this to clarify the question simply by putting it in bold. Not sure why this was put on hold, is it really unclear what he question is or does this stackexchange just not read until the end of a question if they see any code? There was a question mark by the question I'm asking, and it is the last bit of text before parenthesis... and the question suggested by @Jim above is essentially a rewording of my question

Comment: A few comments: (1) nltk is not 100% accurate. Hundred is never a verb. This is a bug. Stackoverflow is a better place to ask. (2) I disagree about the format change, code-style formatting uses monospace which is much easier to read for code, and structured formatting like this. (3) The question lacks proper background research. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hundred defines hundred as a noun, and possibly an adjective, but not as a verb.

Comment: @JasonBassford Based on comments from  jimm101 about readability, would you consider "rolling back" your edit? Although the Q is closed, it might benefit from comments.

Comment: @Cascabel No, I would not. I completely disagree with the comment. Code-style formatting should really only be used for code, and this is not code; I don't think there is nothing here that would benefit from it. I found the original formatting confusing and distracting, and I think it looks much better now.

Comment: The first block is clearly just code, while the second block is clearly not... why not make the first block code?

Answer (score 1):

"Hundred" is always a number. It isn't a verb in any context, so the code used to generate that answer is in some way flawed. How that code is flawed is out of scope here.

Comment: I move that we adjourn.  I second it. I third it... ... I hundred it.

Comment: wouldn't that be "hundredth"?

Comment: I knew someone was gonna catch that.  Maybe the guy who said it didn't know that though.  :-)   You're right of course.  I can't really think of a case either.

Comment: You can deep-six evidence. Zero an instrument. U-D gives _thirtying_. I suspect 'hundred' for 'score a century' isn't far off among some of the more inane of cricket commentaters (though the past simple sounds foul).

Comment: True, but "zero" has a separate definition in the dictionary as a verb, its not just a regular transformation you can make with any number. And "thirtying" isn't actually a word outside U-D... yet. ("Adulting" has become a word recently, so maybe its not far off!)